# Why doesn't this sequence generation work?

Tags: f#

I'm facing with the generation of all the k-combinations (without repetition) of a list of elements. Beside the possible optimization in the code I wrote this function which I was almost sure it should work:

```
// comb :: int -> 'a list -> seq<'a list>
// Generates a sequence of all combinations (no repetition)
let comb k xs =
  // subs :: 'a list -> seq<'a list>
  // Splits a list in its subsequent non-empty tails
  let rec subs xs =
    seq {
      match xs with
      | _::ys -> yield xs
                 yield! subs ys
      | _     -> yield! []
    }

  let rec comb' k xs rs =
    seq {
      for zs in subs xs do
        match k, zs with
        | 0, _                      -> yield rs                        // Solution reached
        | _ when k > List.length zs -> yield! []                       // Safety (and optimizing) guard
        | _, y::ys                  -> yield! comb' (k - 1) ys (y::rs) // Let's go deeper
        | _                         -> yield! []                       // Not a solution
    }

  comb' k xs []
```

The idea behind this algorithm is to "traverse" the tree of all possible combinations and select only the ones with `k` elements; the `subs` function is used to generate the sub-sets of elements to generate the sub-trees in the same level; that is, calling:

```
Seq.toList <| subs [1..3];;
```

produces:

```
[[1;2;3];[2;3];[3]]
```

Maybe this part is a bit confusing, but it shouldn't be part of the problem and I don't think the issue is there.

The algorithm doesn't keep the order of the elements, but it's not necessary for my purpose.

Making a simple test case:

```
Seq.toList <| comb 2 [1..3];;
```

I was expecting the three solutions:

```
[[2;1];[3;1];[3;2]]
```

but actually it returns only:

```
[[2;1]]
```

I debug a little with VS Code, but I didn't really understand how the execution flows.

Does anybody see where the problem is?

**Update**

I realized that I badly exposed the concept behind the algorithm.

I visualized the solution to the problem like a search tree; at every level the root of a subtree contains the solution obtained by the concatenation of the head of all the remaining tails (`subs` results) and the list of the parent node.

Comparing the size of the tails and the current value of `k` I am able to understand which branches can actually contain solutions.

[image: Search tree]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is nearly right.  The only issue is that when `xs` is empty in `comb'`, then `subs` will be empty (since there are no non-empty tails) even when `k` is 0, but you should be yielding `rs` in that case, too.

This can easily be fixed by testing if `k` is 0 outside of the for loop and yielding `rs` there, and then putting the for loop into the else branch (where now you only need to match on `zs`):

```
  let rec comb' k xs rs =
    seq {
      if k = 0 then yield rs
      elif k <= List.length xs then
          for zs in subs xs do
            match zs with
            | y::ys                  -> yield! comb' (k - 1) ys (y::rs) // Let's go deeper
            | []                     -> yield! []                       // Not a solution
    }
```

Comment: Got it! When `subs` produces single element tails, `ys` is empty and at the next recursion falls to the second guard! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, your solution is very confusing, and it's no wonder that it produces incorrect results. Very hard to understand, very hard to follow.

**Problem 1**: `subs` doesn't actually produce all possible subsets. Look: in your very own experiment you're saying that `subs [1..3]` produces `[[1;2;3]; [2;3]; [3]]`. But this is incorrect: `[1;3]` is also a possible subset, but it's missing!

If you look carefully at what `subs` is actually doing, you'll see that at every iteration it emits the current value of `xs`, and then calls itself passing the *tail* of `xs` as argument. This, very predictably, leads to a sequence of *all tails* of the original list.

One obvious way to produce all possible subsets is by, at every iteration level, to produce a sequence of lists with one element removed:

```
  let rec subs xs =
    if List.isEmpty xs then Seq.empty
    else
        seq {
          yield xs
          for i in 0..(List.length xs - 1) do
            let xsWithoutI = (List.take i xs) @ (List.skip (i+1) xs)
            yield! subs xsWithoutI
        }
```

But of course, this will generate repetitions:

```
> subs [1..3] |> Seq.toList
val it : int list list =
    [[1; 2; 3]; [2; 3]; [3]; [2]; [1; 3]; [3]; [1]; [1; 2]; [2]; [1]]
```

I will leave it as an exercise to come up with a way to exclude repetitions.

**Problem 2** the function `comb'` doesn't make sense at all. At every iteration, `zs` is *one* of the possible subsequences (from `subs`), which you then match with `y::ys`, thus making `y` the first element of that subsequence, and `ys` - its tail. Then you prepend the first element of the subsequence to the result, and recur. This means that you're gradually building up the result *out of first elements of every subsequence*, but in reverse order (because you're prepending). So naturally, the result is `[2;1]`: `2` is the first element of the second subsequence, and `1` is the first element of the first subsequence.

The approach doesn't make sense to me at all. I don't see what the thought process could have been that lead to this implementation.

If you have a sequence of all posisble subsequences (from `subs`), and you want only those that are `k` elements long, why not just filter by that?

```
let comb' k xs = subs xs |> Seq.filter (fun s -> List.length s = k)

> comb' 2 [1..3]
val it : seq<int list> = seq [[2; 3]; [1; 3]; [1; 2]]
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really good explaining what's in my head! :-P

I badly described `subs` function (the comment in the code is slightly better): `tails` could be a better name... that is, it doesn't produce the set of all possible subset, but all the subsequent tails and the result of my implementation is conceptually correct... your version is not what I was looking for: using my version the problem with duplicates is avoided.

Comment: About the second problem; the idea is that at every level the function generates all the possible subtrees containing a specific elements: I added an illustration in the post that should make this concept clearer.

Since I have to use this algorithm with a pretty big set of elements (hundreds of thousands) with a big value of `k` (100 or more), I tried to reduce the impact of the computation in terms of memory and performance: your solution will always generate all the possibile combinations no matter the value of `k`.

Comment: Farthermore, mathematically speaking the order of the elements in the combinations generated is not relevant (and as I said, it isn't relevant neither to me); that is, `[1;2]` and `[2;1]` is the same.

I'm very sorry that I was unable to explain the concept clearer.